# How to trigger the event in AnyLogic and then make it cyclic?

Tags: events, anylogic

I would like to make the cyclic event. This event periodically calculates some parameters of the model. However, the event should be triggered once by a condition. I have no idea how to do that.

I tried to make the event.reset() at the beginning and then restart it after the appropriate condition is met.
[image]

However, I received the errors:" agent cannot be resolved to a variable"

If I delete the reset and restart functions for the event, everything will be ok. The event is cyclic and works fine.

The double click on the error shows the stings where the error is occurred (highlighted with red color):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On model start-up, suspend the event by using:

```
event.reset();
```

Once the condition you have is met, use:

```
event.restart();
```

Comment: Thank you! The event monitor some parameters of the agent (like agent.parameter).
When I try to reset it I receive the error "agent can't be resolved to a variable".

Comment: Did this error not occur before adding the reset and restart codes?

Comment: I added some new information to the question. I hope it may helps.

Comment: What happens when you double click on the error? Where does it take you?

Comment: I have added more information to the question ))))

Comment: You will obviously get an error! You are calling `agent` from the event, not the queue...  Your setup is wrong. What exactly are you trying to do? From what I see you don't need a cyclic event, that code should simply be in the queue exit code field.